# Unable to autoload constant Devise::CasSessionsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rubygems

I have a rails project that works locally but when I put it on my development server I get the following error:

```
Unable to autoload constant Devise::CasSessionsController, expected /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/devise_cas_authenticatable-1.9.2/app/controllers/devise/cas_sessions_controller.rb to define it
```

additionally it says:

Extracted source (around line #512):

```
else
      require_or_load(expanded, qualified_name)
      raise LoadError, "Unable to autoload constant #{qualified_name}, expected #{file_path} to define it" unless from_mod.const_defined?(const_name, false)
      return from_mod.const_get(const_name)
end
elsif mod = autoload_module!(from_mod, const_name, qualified_name, path_suffix)
```

Line 512 is:

```
  raise LoadError, "Unable to autoload constant #{qualified_name}, expected #{file_path} to define it" unless from_mod.const_defined?(const_name, false)
```

No idea what to do. This happens when trying to sign in.

Comment: Just checking: you ran `bundle install` on your development server and everything looked OK?

Comment: Yep, I did that and had no issues.